# Change SearchBar & TextField height and width

Tags: swift, tableview, uisearchbar

I try to change my searchbar's height and width, and my textFields height but with the below code I can only change searchbar's height. What is wrong here?

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, self.tableView.frame.size.width - 20, 88))
            let textField = searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
            textField!.bounds.size.height = 66
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

to reload all subviews